# HTTP Status 404 when using the servlet annotation as an url

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, browser, web, ejb-3.1

My js code is like this:

```
window.location.href = "servletAnnotation?"+paramString;
```

servletAnnotation is a webservlet annotation.
Firefox and Chrome both run successfully.
IE shows HTTP Status 404.
Why IE can not identify the url?
How could I make it work successfully?

Comment: Use full url and try like  `baseurl+"servletAnnotation?"+paramString;`

Comment: Thank you.I have tried your method but it doesn't work.